# Getting latex external dependency on meson

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am using pyplot to implement graphics in a GTK application. When I modified matplotlib configurations with

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
...
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

it complains having not found latex:

**RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found**

Other details: I am using gnome builder and it builds as flatpak with all dependencies included.

Comment: Can you make sure you have correctly installed latex locally?

Comment: Yes. I have used it to make tex documents.

Comment: Alright, this can be a link error. What is the full Python traceback? Also, do you get a latex prompt when you execute `latex` in a terminal?

Comment: I do get a prompt when I execute latex in terminal. I think its a problem with adding latex as a external dependency to this meson project, since its built with flatpak.

Comment: The traceback basically says that matplotlib doesnt reconize the latex expression. It is isnt every expression that causes the error, only the more sophisticated that it cannot handle internally.

Comment: Yes, because matplotlib comes with a [minimal TeX distribution](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html). For more advanced math expression, it requires an linkable external latex library. I do not know how to make the link with the meson project.